# How to bind control position to scrolled position of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I want to group DataGrid columns by adding a descriptive header (Label) above:

[image]

("Header 1" above first two columns)

---

When resizing the columns the Label respones as it should:

[image]

("Header 1" still above first two columns)

---

But the label does not move its position when scrolling the DataGrid horizontally:

[image]

("Header 1" no longer above first two columns)

---

I already tried to add everything into a ScrollViewer, but then the headers of the DataGrid and also the Label on top will disappear when scrolling vertically, which they should not.

**Any ideas how to bind horizontal position of the Label to the horizontal scroll  position of the DataGrid? (preferably in xaml only)**

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="600">

<StackPanel Margin="10">
    
    <Grid Height="30" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColId, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColName, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
               Content="Header 1" 
               Background="LightYellow" 
               HorizontalContentAlignment="center" 
               BorderThickness="1" 
               BorderBrush="Black" 
               Margin="0,0,-1,-1"/>
    </Grid>

    <DataGrid Name="dgSimple"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColId"
                                Header="ID"
                                Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColName"
                                Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1"
                                Binding="{Binding Value1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2"
                                Binding="{Binding Value2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        List<Item> items = new()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Name1",
                Value1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                Value2="Sem integer vitae justo eget. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed."
            },
            new Item() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
            new Item() { Id = 3, Name = "Name3" }
        };
        dgSimple.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string Value1 { get; set; } = "";
    public string Value2 { get; set; } = "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is a *markup* language. Don't use it to implement this kind of behaviour. You cannot bind directly to the horizontal offset of the `DataGrid` anyway.

You could handle the `ScrollChanged` event for the `DataGrid`, either directly in the view or in an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF):

```
private void dgSimple_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label.Margin = new Thickness(-e.HorizontalOffset, 0, -1, -1);
}
```

Don't forget to also set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `Label` to `Left` to prevent it from stretching. You could use a converter to set is `Width` property to the sum of the widths of the columns:

```
public class WidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)values[0] + (double)values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Grid.Column="1" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
   Content="Header 1" 
   Background="LightYellow" 
   HorizontalContentAlignment="center" 
   BorderThickness="1" 
   BorderBrush="Black" 
   Margin="0,0,-1,-1">
    <Label.Width>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:WidthConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="ColId" Mode="OneWay" />
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="ColName" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Width>
</Label>
```

Comment: thank you! Works as required. 
I would like to learn and therefore understand what you mean with "Don't use it to implement this kind of behaviour"? Which kind of behaviour? Please give me a hint.

Comment: I mean that you should use a markup language such as XAML to define the layout but use a more expressive and more concise programming language such as C# to actually implement some functionality.